# Why can my IAM user create a bucket but not upload to it?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

**UPDATE:** everything works fine the next day!?! So I think the answer might be that you have to wait some period of time, either after creating a new IAM user, or after creating a new bucket, before uploads will work.

---

I created a dedicated IAM user, then did `aws configure`, and gave the key, and specified the "eu-west-1" region. I can see the correct information in ~/.aws/config.

I tried `aws s3 mb s3://backup` but got told it already existed. `aws s3 ls` confirmed it did not. However `aws s3 mb s3://backup-specialtest` did work.

But when I try `aws s3 cp test.tgz s3://backup-specialtest` I get:

```
A client error (AccessDenied) occurred when calling the CreateMultipartUpload operation: Anonymous users cannot initiate multipart uploads.  Please authenticate.
```

It is not just big files that are the problem. I made a 6-byte text file, and tried to upload with `aws s3 cp test.txt s3://backup-specialtest/` but get:

```
upload failed: ./test.txt to s3://backup-specialtest/test.txt A client error (AccessDenied) occurred when calling the PutObject operation: Access Denied
```

Trying `aws s3 ls s3://backup-specialtest` gives me:

```
A client error (AccessDenied) occurred when calling the ListObjects operation: Access Denied
```

Trying `aws s3api get-bucket-acl --bucket backup-specialtest` gives me:

```
A client error (AccessDenied) occurred when calling the GetBucketAcl operation: Access Denied
```

I had already attached the "AmazonS3FullAccess" policy to my user, in the AWS web console. When I click show policy I get:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "s3:*",
      "Resource": "*"
    }
  ]
}
```

That looks good: he can do all S3 actions, on all resources.

While writing this I thought I'd double-check I could still create a new bucket, and hadn't broken anything along the way. So I tried `aws s3 mb s3://another-test` and got:

```
make_bucket failed: s3://another-test/ A client error (BucketAlreadyExists) occurred when calling the CreateBucket operation: The requested bucket name is not available. The bucket namespace is shared by all users of the system. Please select a different name and try again.
```

But when I try: `aws s3 mb s3://another-test-2` I get success:

```
make_bucket: s3://another-test-2/
```

And it is there: `aws s3 ls`

```
2015-11-13 11:07:10 another-test-2
2015-11-13 10:18:53 backup-specialtest
2014-08-05 21:00:33 something-older
```

(That last bucket appears to have been created by the root user, last year, and is empty.)

Comment: FYI, in normal usage, there is precisely **zero** propagation delay when assigning IAM policy. That's not to say there wasn't some other issue going on in your situation that caused temporary delays.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you need to understand that bucket names are unique across the whole amazon domain. So if a user already has a bucket named "backup", you will not be able to create a new one with this name.

That been said, You have two main ways to manage permissions of buckets.

- When creating a bucket you should have the permission to upload/download by default. You can check this by going to your bucket, click on your bucket name, then "properties" and finally "permission". Here, please check that your IAM user is listed in the granted permissions. You can add other permissions if needed
- otherwise, you also can use bucket policy (same place as permissions mentioned above). You will find bucket policies example [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/fr_fr/AmazonS3/latest/dev/example-bucket-policies.html).
  As an example, something like this one should make your bucket public:

  ```
  {"Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
      {
          "Sid": "myPolicy",
          "Effect": "Allow",
          "Principal": "*",
          "Action": "*",
          "Resource": [
              "arn:aws:s3:::YOUR_BUCKET_NAME/*",
              "arn:aws:s3:::YOUR_BUCKET_NAME"
          ]
      }
  ]}
  ```

Comment: Thanks; I didn't realize bucket names had to be globally unique. I just updated my question to say everything just worked today. Both yesterday and today the permissions had a single entry for the account owner (not explicitly my IAM user). But as it is now working, with those settings, that must be acceptable.

Comment: glad it s working now :)